# How to show any menu fragment(setVisible:ON) while i press button login

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have create a menu login admin for enter the menu admin access in fragment menu. no database just verify the txtuser an passw and if success will show other menu. But i fail again and again , please correction my code 
Thanks.

```
public class Login extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

Button login;
TextView usernme, passw;

public static Login newInstance(){
    return new Login();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logindokter, container, false);

    login = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    usernme = (TextView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
    passw = (TextView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtpassw);

    login.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == R.id.btnLogin) {
        onCreateOptionsMenu();   <--- Error Here //////
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    if(usernme.equals("AdminApp") && passw.equals(R.string.Password))
    {
        menu.findItem(R.id.nav_setting_I).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your logic is wrong because this method onCreateOptionsMenu() already override by the class while it's created you don't need to override manually.

Move this code into Your button click event

```
if(usernme.equals("AdminApp") && passw.equals(R.string.Password))
{
    menu.findItem(R.id.nav_setting_I).setVisible(true);
}
```

Do following
Create Menu variable in your class

```
private Menu menu;
```

in onCreateOptionsMenu() method do following

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sample, menu);
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
this.menu=menu;
}
```

On Button Click Event

```
if(usernme.equals("AdminApp") && passw.equals(R.string.Password)){
        menu.findItem(R.id.nav_setting_I).setVisible(true);
}
```

And in onCreate add this line to make the options appear in your Toolbar

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Comment: but "menu" in  menu.findItem , still red sir

Comment: i have following the code sir, but while i press login button the system not read my username and passw. it's always move to "Cannot Enter".
  if (id == R.id.btnLogin) {
            if (usernme.equals("a") && passw.equals("1")) {
                menu.findItem(R.id.nav_setting_I).setVisible(true);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot Enter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

Comment: @Ren your username and password is wrong that's why it's not entring

Comment: oke now login its work. but i got error with menu. Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference. hha

Comment: @Ren you are not adding any menu to view that's why you are getting null reference check updated answer also mark as a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Ren You need to make a onclick button event on submit button and give the R.id.________ your button id and then you have to call it to your another activity page